# How does this code where elementor is closing a popup work?

Tags: javascript, elementor

if anyone click on text that popup closes. we used this code for closing purpose.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
  $( document ).on( 'click', '.close-popup', function( event ) {
    elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.closePopup( {}, event );
  });
});
```

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=elementor+close+popup+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
```

When jQuery it's loaded and ready

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '.close-popup', function( event )
```

When you click in a element with the class '.close-popup'

```
elementorProFrontend.modules.popup.closePopup( {}, event );
```

Using the elementor library for wordpress close the popup but you should pass the id to the closePopup function in the empty object. Like {"id":popup_id} if not all popups will be closed